# Angular Table only display items when click on table

Tags: angular, asynchronous, request

I have the Angular 7 HTML page with table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let wish of wishes">
    <td>{{ wish.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ wish.wish }}</td>
    <td>{{ wish.price }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also I have a component.ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: 'main.component.html',
  providers: [HttpService, DatePipe],
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  wishes: Wish[] = []; // контейнер желаний
  
  constructor(private commonService: CommonService, private httpService: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder,
              private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.curDateFormated = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData(url).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return this.errorHandler(err, '...');
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.wishes = data.list;
    });
  }
```

And code of my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

But table is filling up only if I click on table or somethere on the page. Yes, I understand, that it occurs because my method getData is working asynchronously, **but how I can handle and fix that problem in my project?**

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to fix your problem.

The first one is to add `ChangeDetectorRef` and use the metod `detectChanges()` after you got your data and assign to a variable. Don't forget to import it to your `component.ts` file.

In your `component.ts` add the following:

```js
constructor( private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, ...){...}

ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData(url).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return this.errorHandler(err, '...');
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.wishes = data.list;
      this._cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

The second option is to use the RxJs library and add a `Subject` and emit a new value after you got your data.

In your `component.ts` add the following in that case:

```js
wishes$$: Subject<Wish[]> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData(url).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return this.errorHandler(err, '...');
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.wishes$$.next(data.list);
    });
  }
```

In your Html:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let wish of wishes$$ | async">
    <td>{{ wish.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ wish.wish }}</td>
    <td>{{ wish.price }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer helped me solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AntonRodrigues, I would appreciate if you mark that answer as the right one.